# Maven can't download artifacts from HTTPS Nexus with mandatory authentication

Tags: java, maven, https, certificate, nexus

I have a Nexus that is available via HTTPS. Only authorized users have rights to access it. Using Maven, when all required artefacts are in local repo, I could even deploy building artefact. But when I remove some of required artifacts from local repository, the build fails.

```
Downloading: https://example.com/nexus/content/groups/all/org/springframework/spring-test-mvc/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-test-mvc-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] example - project1 ..................................... SUCCESS [0.500s]
[INFO] example - project2 ..................................... FAILURE [2.951s]
[INFO] example - project3 ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.599s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 15 13:58:13 EEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project example - project2: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:example-project:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.example:example-project:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE (test), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE (compile), org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1 (test), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.6 (compile), org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (test), junit:junit:jar:4.10 (test), org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0 (test), org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.1 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16 (compile), log4j:apache-log4j-extras:jar:1.1 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:pom:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to nexus (https://example.com/nexus/content/groups/all): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :grc-webclient-services
```

There is the following content in settings.xml of my user:

```
<settings>
<pluginGroups>
    </pluginGroups>
    <proxies>
    </proxies>
    <mirrors>
      <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>https://example.com/nexus/content/groups/all</url>
      </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>

            <id>nexus</id>

            <properties>
                <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonardb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</sonar.jdbc.url>
                <sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>
                <sonar.jdbc.username>sonarusername</sonar.jdbc.username>
                <sonar.jdbc.password>sonarpw</sonar.jdbc.password>
                <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000/</sonar.host.url>
            </properties>


            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://example.com/nexus/content/groups/all</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://example.com/nexus/content/groups/all</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>

        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>all</id>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pw</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>releases</id>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pw</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pw</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

When I downloaded artifacts from this Nexus using wget, I had to add  --no-check-certificate key to skip server's certificate ('cause it's self-signed), and after that I could download it using wget.

I fould Java key -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true, but it didn't change anything at all.

After that I found that it's maybe not a self-signed certificate problem 'cause I've added server's certificate to trusted list using command:

```
keytool -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -import -file certificate.cer
```

Does somebody have an idea how I can download artifacts from Nexus in build-time?

Comment: The russian part was a bit hard to understand :-) But have you tried [this guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure if the previous comment covers what you need. If it is just a matter of accessing the repo on a server with a self signed certificate, adding the certificate to the Java keystore should be enough.

Comment: I've already added one. Maybe not in the proper way. How can I check that certificate is added? Also I've analysed traffic using WireShark while connection to Nexus, I see Encription Alert package with SSL Content-type: Alert (21).

Comment: The "servers" section of your maven settings file is missing an entry for "nexus". I'm assuming you've enabled basic auth? In that case you need specify the username and password that Maven should use when accessing nexus

Comment: Yes, you're right. I resolved this problem several hours ago but couldn't answer my question due to reputation limit. Will answer as sool as will be able.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to change

```
<server>
    <id>all</id>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>pw</password>
</server>
```

to

```
<server>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>pw</password>
</server>
```

where 'nexus' is the identifier of my mirror at the top of `settings.xml`.

Answer (score -3):

Add wagon-http-lightweight extension,Nice Explanation

[Best solution to maven proxy configure](http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/31/how-to-configure-maven-to-work-with-ntlm-proxies/)

Comment: Please add some content and explanation to the body of the answer rather than merely linking to another site for users to read